# Copy entire firefox error console

Tags: firefox, debug

In firefox error console (Ctrl-shift-J in my locale), there is the option of rightclick -> copy to copy one event to clipboard.

I want to save the entire content, while debugging an app, which writes several messages to the logfile.

How to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [Console²](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/console%C2%B2/) addon, you can use Ctrl+A to select all, then Crtl+C to copy and Ctrl+V to paste.